# how to get list of unique item and transpose those values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have below values in a single column

```
May-2017
May-2017
May-2017
Jun-2017
May-2017
Jun-2017
Jun-2017
Jun-2017
Jul-2017
Jul-2017
Jul-2017
Aug-2017
Aug-2017
Aug-2017
Aug-2017
```

So First I want these values in single row That I have successfully implemented using `Transpose` function

```
May-2017    May-2017    May-2017    Jun-2017    May-2017    Jun-2017    Jun-2017    Jun-2017    Jul-2017    Jul-2017    Jul-2017    Aug-2017    Aug-2017    Aug-2017    Aug-2017
```

The problem is I want to get the unique values and make the row like this

```
May-2017    Jun-2017    Jul-2017   Aug-2017
```

Any solution to make this unique?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Remove duplicates. It works in columns, so first copy and paste your values to a new column, remove duplicates (Found in Data, hotkey Alt A M), then transpose them.